# AForge Hough Transform

Tags: geometry, detect

Im trying to do an experiment on how to use the `HoughTransformation` class of AForge. Im using this class to try to count the number of circles on an image. But I always got this error message: Unsupported pixel format of the source image.
Here is my code:

```
private void CountCircles(Bitmap sourceImage)
{
    HoughCircleTransformation circleTransform = new HoughCircleTransformation(15);
    circleTransform.ProcessImage(sourceImage);
    Bitmap houghCircleImage = circleTransform.ToBitmap();
    int numCircles = circleTransform.CirclesCount;
    MessageBox.Show("Number of circles found : "+numCircles.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

HoughCircleTransformation expects a binary bitmap.

```
private void CountCircles(Bitmap sourceImage)
{
    var filter = new FiltersSequence(new IFilter[]
    {
      Grayscale.CommonAlgorithms.BT709,                                                     
      new Threshold(0x40)
    });
    var binaryImage = filter.Apply(bitmap);
    HoughCircleTransformation circleTransform = new HoughCircleTransformation(15);
    circleTransform.ProcessImage(binaryImage);
    Bitmap houghCircleImage = circleTransform.ToBitmap();
    int numCircles = circleTransform.CirclesCount;
    MessageBox.Show("Number of circles found : "+numCircles.ToString());
}
```